# generic function to sort all columns of a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting

I have the following array of objects in my controller

```
$scope.records = [
    {
      "fName" : "Alfreds",
      "lName" : "Berglunds",
      "country" : "Germany",
      "age":21
    },
    {   
      "fName" : "Berglunds",
      "lName" : "Alfreds",
      "country" : "Sweden",
      "age":22
    },
    {      
      "fName" : "Centro",
      "lName" : "Ernst",
      "country" : "Mexico",
      "age":23
    },
    {      
      "fName" : "Ernst",
      "lName" : "Centro",
      "country" : "Austria",
      "age":24
    }
  ]
```

And I am populating a table in my view using the above array

```
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
  <th ng-click="sortByFirstName()">First Nmae</th>
  <th ng-click="sortByLastName()">Last Name</th>
  <th ng-click="sortByCountry()">Country</th>
  <th ng-click="sortByAge()">Age</th>

  <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{x.fName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.lName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On click of each column header, I need to sort the records in ascending order and clicking it again should flip the sorting order(descending order). Right now I am using separate functions to sort them. Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve the same? something like using a generic sort function

Comment: The markup is invalid. `<th>` is not allowed as a direct child of `<table>`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a **`generic function`** with angularjs $filter by passing the **`sortBy`** as a parameter to the function

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$filter){
$scope.sortBy = function(sortBy){
    $scope.records = $filter('orderBy')($scope.records, sortBy);
}
$scope.records = [
    {
      "fName" : "Alfreds",
      "lName" : "Berglunds",
      "country" : "Germany",
      "age":21
    },
    {   
      "fName" : "Berglunds",
      "lName" : "Alfreds",
      "country" : "Sweden",
      "age":22
    },
    {      
      "fName" : "Centro",
      "lName" : "Ernst",
      "country" : "Mexico",
      "age":23
    },
    {      
      "fName" : "Ernst",
      "lName" : "Centro",
      "country" : "Austria",
      "age":24
    }
  ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
  <th ng-click="sortBy('fName')">First Nmae</th>
  <th ng-click="sortBy('lName')">Last Name</th>
  <th ng-click="sortBy('country')">Country</th>
  <th ng-click="sortBy('age')">Age</th>

  <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{x.fName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.lName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution works even though `th` is a direct descendant of `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this generic `sortBy` and pass the property name to it

```
var sortBy = ( prop ) => $scope.records.sort(  function( a, b ){
   return typeof a == "number" ? ( a[ prop ] - b[ prop ] ) : a[ prop ].localeCompare( b[ prop ] );
});
```

For example

```
sortBy ( "fName" );
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am not aware of angularjs, hence posting only vanilla js solution.